# What do the dollar ($) and percentage (%) signs represent in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I am trying to understand how the assembly language works for a micro-computer architecture class, and I keep facing different syntaxes in examples:

```
sub $48, %esp
mov %eax, 32(%esp)
```

What do these codes mean? What is the 32 operand an addition to the esp register?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Thats not Intel syntax, its [AT&T syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax), also called [GAS syntax](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax).

the `$` prefix is for immediates (constants), and the `%` prefix is for registers (they are *required*<sup>1</sup>).

For more about AT&T syntax, see also [the `[att]` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info).

---

<sup>1</sup> Unless the `noprefix` option is specified, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549347/how-to-use-address-constants-in-gcc-x86-inline-assembly) & [here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dVariations.html).  But usually `noprefix` is only used with `.intel_syntax noprefix`, to get MASM-like syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not know where to look for this

Comment: the `%` prefix is not required if using `noprefix` directive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549347/how-to-use-address-constants-in-gcc-x86-inline-assembly

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Interesting, I've see that directive before, probably cause its extremely poorly documented :( https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dVariations.html

Comment: that's funny but I've never seen percent mark % being used.

Answer (score 20):

Compared to Intel syntax, AT&T syntax has many differences

- `$` signifies a constant (integer literal). Without it the number is an absolute address
- `%` denotes a register
- The source/destination order is reversed
- `()` is used for memory reference, like `[]` in Intel syntax

So the above snippet is equivalent to

```
sub esp, 48         ; esp -= 48
mov [esp+32], eax   ; store eax to the value at the address `esp + 32`
```

Comment: Hi - I'm not sure this actually answers the question... what are the $ and % ?

Comment: @TarynEast they are prefixes for immidiates and registers like Necrolis has said

Comment: Your post showed up in the "low quality" review queue... for not having enough explanation in it. My recommendation was based on that... Feel free to edit it to say what you have said above ;)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, "32(%esp)" indicates an offset of 32 from %esp.

Comment: GAS calls it "Memory References", documented at: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.18/as/i386_002dMemory.html x86 concept summarized brilliantly at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Addressing_modes

Answer (score 1):

As @Necrolis said, that's written in AT&T syntax.  It means:

```
subtract 48 from the register esp (the stack pointer).
store the contents of eax to the four bytes starting at (esp + 32).
```

Answer (score 0):

This is AT&T syntax for x86. In AT&T `%` generally denotes a register while `$` is reserved for immediates. If you omit th `$` the assembler would interpret the 48 as an address.