# Meaning of dollar sign in gnu assembly labels

Tags: gcc, assembly

What is the meaning of a dollar sign in front of a gnu assembly label?

For example, what is the difference between `mov msg, %si` and `mov $msg, %si`

(For more context, I'm playing around with the x86 Bare Metal Examples: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/master/bios_hello_world.S)

```
#include "common.h"
BEGIN
    mov $msg, %si
    mov $0x0e, %ah
loop:
    lodsb
    or %al, %al
    jz halt
    int $0x10
    jmp loop
halt:
    hlt
msg:
    .asciz "hello world"
```

([What do the dollar ($) and percentage (%) signs represent in assembly intel x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196655/what-do-the-dollar-and-percentage-signs-represent-in-assembly-intel-x86) discusses the general use of % before registers and $ before constants; but, I don't think it lays out the use of $ with labels nearly as clearly as the answer below )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do the dollar ($) and percentage (%) signs represent in assembly intel x86?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196655/what-do-the-dollar-and-percentage-signs-represent-in-assembly-intel-x86)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You use $(dollar) sign when addressing a constant, e.g.: 
`movl $1, %eax` (put `1` to `%eax` register) 
or when handling an address of some variable, e.g.: `movl $var, %eax` (this means take an **address of** `var` **label** and put it into `%eax` register). 
If you **don't use** dollar sign that would mean "take the **value from** `var` **label** and put it to register".

Comment: That makes sense.  If that is the case, then shouldn't the labels used with jmp also begin with $?

Comment: Why can't you use "jmp $loop" (jmp with $). Would it do something different? Is is valid syntax or not? And what exactly would be stored in eax if you use "movl var, %eax"? Is it even valid syntax? Is it perhaps equivalent to movl ($var), %eax?